# Receiving 'ErrorAccessDenied' response code , when an outlook web add-in issues a GetItem request via the makeEwsRequestAsync api

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js

We are testing an Outlook Web Add-in with different combinations of Exchange Server and Outlook client versions.

The add-in makes a `GetItem` request via the [makeEwsRequestAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox#makeewsrequestasyncdata-callback-usercontext) API:

```soap
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <GetItem 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
            <ItemShape>
                <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
                <t:IncludeMimeContent>true</t:IncludeMimeContent>
            </ItemShape>
            <ItemIds>
                <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGMwMDQxMDZhLTc5ODgtNDY5Yi1iYzk1LThlZDMyYjNiOTI3MgBGAAAAAACAJypvrerqS79u4AuHwVA6BwDco3spzUIpR7WutkjxuhkZAAAAAAEMAADco3spzUIpR7WutkjxuhkZAAA3RsNcAAA="/>
            </ItemIds>
        </GetItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When we tested using Exchange Server 2016 with Outlook for Windows 2013, the `GetItem` operation fails with the following response:

```soap
<s:Envelope 
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="225" MinorBuildNumber="41" Version="V2_48" 
            xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <m:GetItemResponse 
            xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
            xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <m:ResponseMessages>
                <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
                    <m:MessageText>Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.</m:MessageText>
                    <m:ResponseCode>ErrorAccessDenied</m:ResponseCode>
                    <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
                    <m:Items/>
                </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
            </m:ResponseMessages>
        </m:GetItemResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

For the same account if we try from Outlook 2016 for Windows or from the Outlook Web App, the add-in works fine.

How could I debug this further? Is there any known limitation? Could you please help.

**JS Code for framing request:**

```
function addSoapEnvelope(body) {

var request =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
    '               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
    '               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
    '               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
    '               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
    '  <soap:Header>' +
    '    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />' +
    '  </soap:Header>' +
    '  <soap:Body>' + body + '</soap:Body>' +
    ' </soap:Envelope>';

return request;
```

}

```
function getItemRequest(id) {
var body = 
    '<GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">' +     
    '      <ItemShape>  <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>  <t:IncludeMimeContent>true</t:IncludeMimeContent>  </ItemShape>' +
    '      <ItemIds><t:ItemId Id="' + id + '"/></ItemIds>' +
    '</GetItem>';
return addSoapEnvelope(body);
```

}

var request = getItemRequest(itemid);

Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, getMessageCallBack, requestContext);

**EWS logs from exchange server**

2017-08-17T13:07:30.548Z,32e3b547-77aa-451c-9981-fbccecec0769,15,0,847,30,,Bearer,True,**user1_mailbox@qa.sample.com**,qa.sample.com,Microsoft Office/15.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Outlook 15.0.4805;

Office extension have no permissions to access any other mailboxes then the mailbox provided in the user context.    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.StoreSessionCacheBase.ConnectOnce(ExchangePrincipal mailboxToAccess  CallContext callContext  Boolean unifiedLogon)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.StoreSessionCacheBase.CreateMailboxSessionBasedOnAccessType(ExchangePrincipal mailboxToAccess  CallContext callContext  Boolean unifiedLogon)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.AppWideStoreSessionCache.GetCachedMailboxSessionByGuid(Guid mailboxGuid  CallContext callContext  Boolean unifiedLogon)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.MethodWideStoreSessionCache.GetCachedStoreSessionByMailboxGuid(Guid mailboxGuid  Boolean unifiedLogon)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.MethodWideStoreSessionCache.GetCachedMailboxSession(MailboxId mailboxId  Boolean unifiedLogon)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.IdConverter.ConvertId(CallContext callContext  IdHeaderInformation headerInformation  ConvertOption convertOption  BasicTypes expectedType  List`1 attachmentIds  String changeKey  Int32 hashCode  Boolean unifiedLogon  Item& cachedItem)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.IdConverter.ConvertItemIdToIdAndSession(BaseItemId baseItemId  ConvertOption convertOption  BasicTypes expectedType  Item& cachedItem)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.GetItem.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()    at Microsoft.Exchange.Common.IL.ILUtil.DoTryFilterCatch(TryDelegate tryDelegate  FilterDelegate filterDelegate  CatchDelegate catchDelegate)    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.GetItem.Execute()    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.ExceptionHandler`1.Execute(CreateServiceResult createServiceResult  Int32 index  GenerateMessageXmlForServiceError generateErrorXml);

Comment: I'm assuming you already checked but just in case, have you enabled `OAuthAuthentication` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services#authentication-and-permission-considerations-for-the-makeewsrequestasync-method))?

Comment: Yes. I checked OAuthAuthentication is enabled. Also if account has EWSAccess. Strangely this seem to come only for Exchange2016 account using Outlook 2013 for Windows. For the same account, plugins works in Outlook 2016 and OWA clients.

Comment: can you post the JS code you're executing?

Comment: Hi, Have udated the quested with JS snippet.

Comment: Now we are getting this error for Exchange 2013 account in Outlook for windows 2013 as well. This was working fine till very recently. Even now the plugin works in OWA from browsers. This looks more like an environment issue. Any help in how we can deug this further?

Comment: Have updated the question with EWS logs. The outlook client has mulitple email addresses configured. Looks like when the makeEWSRequestAsync call is made , the email address sent to the backend is incorrect. In the EWS logs it says 'user1_mailbox@qa.sample.com'. But the action is performed on an item belonging to another email address.

Comment: 2 questions:
1.  You noted the item belongs to another email address.  Is the addin open from an item that belongs to 'user1_mailbox@qa.sample.com'?
2.  What is the build number of the Outlook 2013?  It would be interesting to get the Exchange2016/Exchange2013 and Outlook 2016 build numbers as well. Tt sounds like Outlook 2013 is the most important one, because it's the common in all the repros.

Comment: From the Logs it looks like you are on Outlook 15.0.4805. This version of Outlook is somewhat old. Can you grab the latest Outlook 2013 updates: 

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outlook-updates-472c2322-23a4-4014-8f02-bbc09ad62213

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011078/description-of-the-security-update-for-outlook-2013-july-27-2017

Comment: You may also want to grab all the possible updates for Office as well. 

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3203489/july-11-2017-update-for-office-2013-kb3203489

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Update-history-for-Office-2013-19214f38-85b7-4734-b2f8-a6a598bb0117