# exchangelib suddenly throws ErrorAccessDenied, but credentials are still valid

Tags: python, exchangelib

The title pretty much says it all. I was able to access my Exchange server using the following method:

```
credentials = Credentials(
    username='DOMAIN\\username',
    password='PASSWORD')

exchange_account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address='someone@somewhere.com',
    credentials=credentials,
    autodiscover=True,
    access_type=DELEGATE)

sent_items = exchange_account.sent.all().filter(datetime_received__range=(last_date, now))[:10]
```

However, it suddenly stopped working, and now the last line throws `exchangelib.errors.ErrorAccessDenied`, despite the fact that the credentials are still valid (they work on Outlook and on an Android email client).

I guess the server somehow detected the activity and blocked it thinking it was fraudulent. Can someone suggest what I need to ask the Exchange server admin to look for and correct? It's hosted at intermedia.net, if that helps.

I'd much appreciate the help.

Comment: While the credentials are still valid, it's possible that the `username` user no longer has delegate access to the `someone@somewhere.com` account. My best bet would be to verify this with your Exchange admin.

Comment: Thank you. Is that possible even if that is the assigned account for that particular user? I mean, this is not one user trying to access someone else's account. It is the user trying to access his own account. Or maybe I shouldn't be using access_type=DELEGATE?

Comment: Well that's strange. DELEGATE is usually the correct access type in this situation, but you could always try IMPERSONATION.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried that, and it returned ErrorImpersonateUserDenied. It probably has something to do with the setup that 'DOMAIN\\username' is something like 'EXCH01\\jdoe_company', but the email address is 'jdoe@company.com', which probably requires delegate access. Still, I'm confused that Outlook and the Android mail client can both still access the inbox, but exchangelib with the identical credentials cannot.

Comment: I found a solution. I'm posting it here in case it helps someone else. In defining the configuration, instead of using autodiscover, I had to explicitly define the service_endpoint (https://region.server.domain.net/EWS/Exchange.asmx), rather than just putting in the server and letting it autodiscover.

Comment: Well, that worked for about 2 minutes and now I am getting the AccessDenied error again. Something must be happening that is making the server disable EWS access.

Comment: There's a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593520/receiving-erroraccessdenied-response-code-when-an-outlook-web-add-in-issues If possible, contact your Exchange admins and have them debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks again for your attentiveness. I was working with the Exchange admin to try to diagnose the problem, and in creating a minimum script to reproduce the error, I found that the problem actually comes from a very unexpected place. This line causes the problem: sent_items = exchange_account.sent.all().filter(datetime_received__range=(last_date, now))[:10] and as long as the last date is 'now' and the number of messaged requested is small (<100 or so) I actually get the last messages. But once I've gotten those, I want to get the 10 previous messages, then it fails with AccessDenied.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. It would have been nice if you posted the code that raised the error at the beginning. Anyway, `ErrorAccessDenied` is usually raised by the server when you are requesting an item, or private fields on a private item, that you don't have access to. While it sounds strange, it's possible that your sent folder somehow contains items that you don't have access to. You can try to narrow it down by fetching items in short date ranges until you hit something that raises `ErrorAccessDenied`. If you enable debug logging, the request and response XML will tell you the exact ID.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, unfortunately I didn't know that that could happen, so assumed the provider had some functionality that was blocking me. It was only when I tried to get the last 10 again that I realized it wasn't that. I found an offending item that was resulting in the behavior described above. Oddly, it was in my "Sent Items", so I'm not sure why that would be. Specifically it was a response to a meeting request item that had been forwarded to me. If I can bother you one more time, is there any way to avoid such items, or should I just try items one at a time? Don't want to hammer the server.

Comment: It's possible that the meeting request for some reason has private fields. In that case, you might get around the issue by only requesting non-private fields from the sent items, e.g. `exchange_account.sent.all().only('subject', 'start', 'end')`. Otherwise, if you can find the misbehaving item and are allowed to delete it, just do that :-)

Comment: Many thanks! I think this gets to the bottom of the issue. There were a few misbehaving items. I just kept trying until I found them and was able to delete them all. Now my whole sent items box can be synced. When another one pops up, I'll try as you suggest to isolate the specific offending element. You've been a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

[extracting comments into an actual answer]

`ErrorAccessDenied` is usually raised by the server when you are requesting an item, or private fields on a private item, that you don't have access to. While it sounds strange, it's possible that your sent folder contains items that you don't have access to. You can narrow it down by fetching items in small chunks until you hit something that raises `ErrorAccessDenied`. If you enable debug logging, the request and response XML will tell you the exact ID.

You may get around the issue by only requesting non-private fields from the sent items, e.g. `exchange_account.sent.all().only('subject', 'start', 'end')`. Otherwise, if you can find the misbehaving item and are allowed to delete it, just do that.